# Is there any way to do token base auth in asp.net core application without redundant stuffs?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

Anyone have a good example to do token based authorization in asp.net core without this crap like IdentityContext and other? I just want to set up settings for token generating in order to my system can generate and check token in right way and I want to manage authentication process by myself. Thanks

Having used a solution from this article go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=84547:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = Configuration["AuthOptions:Authority"];
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["AuthOptions:Issuer"],
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AuthOptions:Key"])),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
        });
        services.AddMvc();
        ConfigureDependincies(services);
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var configuration = new SlackConfiguration
        {
            WebhookUrl = new Uri("https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"),
            MinLevel = LogLevel.Warning
        };

        loggerFactory.AddSlack(configuration, env);
        //  loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        //{
        //  AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        //  AutomaticChallenge = true,
        //  RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        //  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        //  {

        //      ValidIssuer = Configuration["AuthOptions:Issuer"],
        //      ValidateAudience = false,
        //      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        //      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AuthOptions:Key"])),
        //      ValidateLifetime = true,
        //  }
        //});
        app.UseMvc();
    }


        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                 issuer: _root["AuthOptions:Issuer"],
                 notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                 claims: identity.Claims,
                 expires: DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_root["AuthOptions:TokenLifeTime"]))),
                 signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_root["AuthOptions:Key"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512)
         );
        return token;
```

It's working for me.

Comment: you might want to look into how I did it below. The jwtSecurityToken had issues in the past with security. And yours has a huge security issue. Anyone can recreate your `SigningCredentials` if they can read your appsettings. It's in plain text on the server... not in memory, not crypto secure, just sitting there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, you mean that I need to encrypt my secret key before using it?

Comment: you should be using a certificate, or a secret key + random generated string on startup that will be stored on memory. This is to prevent them from getting your key if they ever get a glimpse at your disk. But I would at least use RFC2898DeriveBytes to hash your secret key.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hashing  secret_key :). About "secret key + random generated string on startup". It's a good case, but I'm using the microservice architecture where is api gateway, auth service and other small microservices. I want that api gateway has an opportunity to get a token from auth service and have an access to other microservices. In this case I need that all my microservices have equal secret_key to recognize token if I right understand. How to be in this case?

Comment: you really should only have one authentication service, and all the other apps/microservices use yours to authenticate. Having every web api use it's own security just feels wrong.

Comment: Actually, it is definitely wrong. You only want to authorize a user or service per web api. You do not want to authenticate them. It's hard to separate them logically some times, but you don't want to mix authentication with authorization.

Comment: I'm having only one authentication service, but other microservices should know if token sent from api gateway is valid. So, for that I need to set up token settings like audience, sekret_key for all services, right?

Comment: No that's the job of the authentication service.

Comment: So, on every request from API gateway to a microservice I should send a token to auth service for verification it ?

Comment: Yes, and then it is the job of the microservice to authorize the action.

Comment: So if the token sent to the auth service is valid, the return is a new token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in following way

1. Have a token generator API endpoint (controller) i.e. http://localhost/auth/token
2. In this, you generate token by verifying the authenticate user (check user against store)
3. The generated token can be validated by providing authentication schema in ASP.NET Core pipeline. app.AddAuthentication()
4. Any subsequent calls to API, should have Authorization header with generated token.

This approach can be refined accordingly.

Comment: thanks. I had used  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication() and it works well for me, but now is obsolete. I was trying find out a good example by https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core and use it out of the box, but all examples contains unused for me code with set up own authentication process

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.0 changed it, just check samples in security repo of github page of ASP.NET, there is a good example for it. I am using that itself. let me know if you dont find it

Answer (score 1):

I've done this very thing. I got sick of all the third party things so I wrote my own.

You want to create tokens and provide them/ validate them through an api.

Here is an example of the api controller that creates the token initially.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TokenController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TokenCreatorOption _tco;
        private readonly CryptoHash _ch;

        public TokenController(IOptions<TokenCreatorOption> ioptTCO, IOptions<CryptoHash> ioptCH, IOptions<ConnectionStrings> ioptConn)
        {
            _tco = ioptTCO.Value;
            _ch = ioptCH.Value;
        }


        [HttpPost("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IssueToken([FromBody] CredentialUser model)
        {
            ///if model is null, this is an incorrect format
            if(model == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var user = GetUserFromDatabaseOrStore(model.userName, model.passWord);

            if(user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            TokenCreatorOption newTCO = _tco; ///get your initial instantiation of the TokenCreatorOption. This is set to default values based off appsettings or in configure services

            newTCO.UserObject = user;
            newTCO.Expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ss tt");

            ///anything within the TokenCreatorOption will be hashed, anything in the token Provider is not going to be hashed (not secured), but acts as a good object to store just general things that are needed on client side.
            TokenProvider _tpo = new TokenProvider();
            _tpo.tco = TokenInteraction.CreateToken(newTCO, _ch.salt);
            _tpo.listApp = xapp; ///put anything you wouldn't want to be hashed and claimed against outside of the object. so you always validate things inside the tco, but never exclude anything inside tco. This was a fatal flaw in tokens in the past.

            ///this is using messagepack to serialize, to make it smaller since this is going to be passed between every request/response. Consider zipping as well if large enough.
            var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<TokenProvider>();
            byte[] obj = null;

            using (var byteStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Pack(byteStream, _tpo);
                obj = byteStream.ToArray();
            }

            return File(obj, "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

> TokenCreatorOption Class

```
public class TokenCreatorOption
    {
        public string Issuer { get; set; }

        public UserFromThatDatabaseOrStore UserObject { get; set; }

        public string Expiration { get; set; }

        public string HashValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Notice that all these objects in `TokenCreatorOption` are claims. Every single one is checked in the hash function.

Here is the Token Creator and the Token Validator, once a token is valid, you can reissue a new one.

> TokenInteraction

```
public static class TokenInteraction
    {
        public static TokenCreatorOption CreateToken(TokenCreatorOption _tco, byte[] salt)
        {
            byte[] exp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tco.Expiration);
            byte[] issuer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tco.Issuer);
            byte[] user = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_tco.UserObject));
            byte[] salty = salt;

            IEnumerable<byte> rv = exp.Concat(issuer).Concat(user).Concat(salty);
            HashAlgorithm alg = SHA512.Create();
            _tco.HashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(alg.ComputeHash(rv.ToArray()));

            return _tco;
        }

        public static bool ValidateToken(TokenCreatorOption _tco, byte[] salt)
        {
            byte[] exp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tco.Expiration);
            byte[] issuer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tco.Issuer);
            byte[] user = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_tco.UserObject));
            byte[] salty = salt;

            IEnumerable<byte> rv = exp.Concat(issuer).Concat(user).Concat(salty);
            HashAlgorithm alg = SHA512.Create();

            if (_tco.HashValue != Convert.ToBase64String(alg.ComputeHash(rv.ToArray())))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Notice in `TokenInteraction` The order of bytes added to `rv` needs to be in the same order when we validate the token.

Now we can have a validate controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValidateController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TokenCreatorOption _tco;
        private readonly CryptoHash _ch;

        public ValidateController(IOptions<TokenCreatorOption> ioptTCO, IOptions<CryptoHash> ioptCH)
        {
            _tco = ioptTCO.Value;
            _ch = ioptCH.Value;
        }


        [HttpPost("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateToken([FromBody] TokenCreatorOption model)
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Model Cannot be Null");
            }

            ///Kick them right now if session is expired, so we don't have to do the full hashing.    
            if (DateTime.ParseExact(model.Expiration, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                return BadRequest("Expired Datetime");
            }
            if(!TokenInteraction.ValidateToken(model, _ch.salt))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            model.Expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ss tt");

            TokenProvider _tpo = new TokenProvider();
            _tpo.tco = TokenInteraction.CreateToken(model, _ch.salt);


            var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<TokenProvider>();
            byte[] obj = null;

            using (var byteStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Pack(byteStream, _tpo);
                obj = byteStream.ToArray();
            }

            return File(obj, "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

And of course when you are initially registering the services. Create your salt value either through a cert, or through a random crypto number generator.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SingleApiVersion(new Swashbuckle.Swagger.Model.Info
                {
                    Version = "v1"
                });


            services.Configure<TokenCreatorOption>(myopt =>
            {
                myopt.Issuer = "Issuer"; //either from appsettings or manually
                myopt.Expiration = null;
                myopt.UserObject = null;
                myopt.HashValue = "";
            });
            byte[] salty;
            new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salty = new byte[64]);
            services.Configure<CryptoHash>(copt =>
            {
                copt.salt = (new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("Super!SecretKey!123456789!@#$", salty, 1000)).GetBytes(64);
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```